# Putting a max-height on an element creates horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I've been working on making a drop-down menu that has a max-height, and puts vertical scrollbars on the element if it exceeds it. For some reason, when this vertical scrollbar is added, the width does not automatically adjust to compensate for the width of the vertical scrollbar, and creates a horizontal one as well.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e00dp7w/) so you can see a simplified version of my problem. Anyone have a good solution (besides setting a width on it, because I want it to adjust to the content inside, and preferably no JavaScript)?

```
.wrapper { display:inline-block; max-height:200px; overflow-y:auto; background:#f00;}

.wrapper > a { display:inline-block; padding:20px; white-space:nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow-y:scroll`.

```
.wrapper {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4e00dp7w/2/

Note that `overflow-x:hidden` is not really needed, but just in case.

Comment: You are the quicker.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: overflow-y:scroll makes a scrollbar appear at all times. I only want it to show it if the child goes out of the max-height I set (a lot of the time it won't in my scenario)

Answer (score 1):

When the vertical scrollbar is added, it will take some space from inside the container, in this case `.wrapper`. To avoid this, you can add `overflow-x: hidden` to your `.wrapper.` class like this:

```
.wrapper { 
    display:inline-block;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background:#f00;
}
```

However, as i said, it takes space from inside the container, so your content may be overlayed by the scrollbar. A workaround to this problem is adding a little padding to your `.wrapper` class to compensate this space ocupied by the scrollbar.

```
.wrapper { 
    display:inline-block;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background:#f00;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4e00dp7w/7/

Answer (score 0):

I would set...

```html
.wrapper{
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

that way a scroll bar will only show if the inner content is taller than the wrapper.

Comment: That will cut off some of the padding on the right hand side. I want 20px padding all around the items, but my way and this way both will cut some of it off.